# how create numpy array with for loop

Tags: python, loops

Hello sorry for my english i'm not native and not good

so i have some question I am creating a function in python that multiplies a desired number by a whole consecutive integer. the heart of my problem is how to indent this number instead of using .append is there a way like on R to add the element using j[i] instead of .append having previously declared the matrix

```
def carr(inte,numb):
    car = []
    i=0
    for i in range(numb):
        car.append(inte*i)
        i += 1
        return print(car) 
    
carr(2,9)
```

Comment: could you give some examples of what the function is supposed to return? For example, what should carr(2,9) return?

Comment: Additionally, you currently have a return statement inside the for loop. What would happen right now is:
>i is set to zero
>zero (inte * 0) is appended to car
>i is incremented
>car is printed
>function ends

Answer (score 0):

The exact thing you are doing can be done as
[inte * i for i in range(numb)]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping explicitly, use numpy’s vectorised operations:

```
def carr(inte, numb):
    return numpy.array(range(numb)) * inte
```

Incidentally, in R you’d do something equivalent (along the lines of `seq(n) * x`): R uses loops even less than Python; and what you suggested would be inefficient and unnecessarily convoluted in R.

As an additional note, spend some time thinking about your variable names: neither `carr` nor `inte` or `numb` are expressive, it’s a complete mystery what they are supposed to represent.